# How can I reset the cloth to its original (start) position?

Tags: unity, cloth

I got a cube that is a cloth and it doesn't have any forces applied to it.

It has a ball inside and I can move the ball inside to collide with the cube cloth and make a nice animation.

Sometimes, if I move the ball too fast, the cloth breaks and the ball goes outside the cube. This makes the cloth fly away.

I need some way to reset the cloth to its original form.

Comment: Store vertex positions of the cube and then just re-apply them whenever you want

Comment: My temporal unefficient solution is Destroy() the current cloth, and Instantiate() a new one. I'll try your solution Nick. Thanks.